# If i install a maven project with IntelliJ, i put the quartz repository,where i should put the quartz.properties file?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I install a `maven` project with `IntelliJ`, I put the quartz repository in `pom.xml`.

Where should I put the `quartz.properties` file?

I know it default in the External Libraries,but I don't know how to handle the `quartz.properties` by myself.